# GCP Cloud Composer pods is forbidden: User system:anonymous cannot list resource pods in API group in the namespace \"customnamespace\"

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-composer

I want to run a DAG on Cloud Composer but error message said

`kubernetes.client.exceptions.ApiException: (403) Reason: Forbidden HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Audit-Id': '-4fd3-44e8-80c2-adc3747ab748', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-Kubernetes-Pf-Flowschema-Uid': '-1a5d-4108-b7d6-685f4a37a670', 'X-Kubernetes-Pf-Prioritylevel-Uid': '-5c1a-4ee9-b44d-86ebe3f8eaa1', 'Date': 'Tue, 07 Nov 2023 12:04:26 GMT', 'Content-Length': '257'}) HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"pods is forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot list resource \"pods\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"customnamespace\"","reason":"Forbidden","details":{"kind":"pods"},"code":403}`

The error I have on Logging :

`print credential failed with error: Failed to retrieve access token:: failure while executing gcloud, with args`

The image version is : composer-2.3.5-airflow-2.5.3

The service accounts roles have not changed since last time it was working

Comment: Definitely looks like your login is failing so it's not really the fact you are trying to run a DAG but your `gcloud` login is failing.